# button shows different behavior when closing a tab in plain html and in localhost (apache) after html5 required attribute was added

Tags: javascript, html

Good day,

I am working on a form where all my text fields have a required attribute; I have two buttons which submits the values of the text field and the other an **image** button that closes the tab.

It was working great and does what it is coded to but when i added html required attribute i encountered this weird behavior on my form.

Submit button does exactly what i want but the close button is not closing the tab; I had tried multiple codes to get my tab closed but it only works on html but when i set it to localhost it does not work anymore; I have listed all the things i have tried below.

Works on plain html but not when set to localhost (apache)

1. Original coding without required attribute.

```
<input name="close" value="Close" onclick="self.close()" src="../img/close.png" class="submit_button" type="image" height="28" width="28" formnovalidate>
```

2. `<a href="javascript:window.open(",'_self).close();">Close</a>` ( I thought of using a hyperlink to avoid the issues with submit and button tag but would unfortunately it did not work for me )
3. This uses a JS confirm if it will close a tab or not

```
<button name="close" onclick="Exit()" type="button" formnovalidate><img src="../img/close.png" style="height: 28px; width: 28px;"></button>
```

My question now is why does the onclick close tab function or condition not working when the required attribute was added? Why is it having this behavior?

Any help is much appreciated; Thanks.

Comment: Your code is always `html`, probably you mean opening the file without a webserver `file:///...`  and with a webserver `http://localhost/`. Anyway `.close()` will only work for windows/tabs that where opened using javascript (`window.open`). What error message do you see in the developer console of your browser.

Comment: @t.niese thanks for the response and for correcting how i interpreted my weird issue; All three works fine without a webserver but when its opened with a webserver it does not have an give out any error it basically does not execute close tab code.

Comment: I check the developer console and here is what i got

1. Does not give an error and goes to the next form (It executed the action on the form)
2. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
3. Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

Why is that happening when it works perfectly when you open it without a webserver and it also work before i added that html 5 required attribute

Comment: all set now i got it all working now; for some reason the self_close works when the button from my previous page is click but if i go directly to the page i have in question it does not work.

i was so focus on getting this page working i forgot that i had a condition on my previous page that needs to be met first before this page executes.